# Finding partial subsets python

Tags: python, set

I'm looking for a way to get the number of elements of one `set` that appear in another `set`.

Given these two sets:

```
a = 'a b c d'
b = 'a b c e f'
a = set(a.split())
b = set(b.split())
```

This prints false:

```
print a.issubset(b) # prints False
```

Is there a pythonic way to instead print "3" since three elements of `a` appear in `b`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
>>> a.issubset(b)
False
>>> a.intersection(b)
{'a', 'c', 'b'}
>>> len(a.intersection(b))
3
```

which could be abbreviated `&` since both `a` and `b` are sets:

```
>>> len(a & b)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you `&` and `|` to perform simple set algebra on python sets.

For example:

```
> a & b
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
> a | b
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
```